# Foundtion's Orbit Slider fades not automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

i have a problem with foundation's orbit slider:

the images fades not automatically.

http://www.pruefag.ch/de/

what i'm doing wrong?

`<ul class="example-orbit orbit-slides-container" data-orbit data-options="timer_speed:4000;animation:fade;animation_speed:3000;timer: false" style="height: 546px;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the `timer` option set to `false`. This will disable the timer, thus stopping the transition effect. Simply remove the option or set it to `true`:

```
<ul class="example-orbit orbit-slides-container" data-orbit data-options="timer_speed:4000;animation:fade;animation_speed:3000;" style="height: 546px;">
  //Your content
</ul>
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/oqzemwj7/)